# How do I parse data from php using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a data from php fired to my js controller. I want these data to be parsed and stored individually so I can assign them to their respective DOMS.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
$userData = name=Ben&age=21&gender=male&alive=true;
```

as you can see, the data is in whole text. How am I able to parse that text into javascipt, something like this:

```
console.log(userData.name); // == Ben
console.log(userData.age); // == 21
console.log(userData.gender); // == male
console.log(userData.alive); // == true
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: i see. thanks i ddnt know its called query_strings. should i delete this post?

Comment: Up to you. Btw: why you are not sending data in Json format?

Comment: @k102 Should I? i thought query_strings are better?

Comment: No, since json is well supported on both ends: you can easily `json_encode` anything at php side, then get it in js